# Why can I skip the blank on command line arguments (.e.g, script -ARGNAMEargvalue)?

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, arguments, args

I sometimes see command line calls to programs/scripts with `optional arguments`, where the **whitespace** between the argument and the value is skipped, e.g.,:

```
scriptname -ARGNAMEargvalue
```

I find it tough to find documentation around this. I would be happy if someone could just hint me to the correct "search phrase" or an existing SO post.

Comment: It always depends on how parsing of command line arguments is implemented in that specific script.

Comment: `Why can I skip` Because someone programmed the `sciptname` program so that you are able to do this. `to find documentation` refer to `scriptname` documentation, there is no "global" documentation.

Comment: Bash uses internal variable  `IFS` for word splitting. There are special rules for handling whitespace characters in IFS, in any of the field-splitting situations above (the first two bullet points). Whitespace IFS characters at the beginning and end of a string are removed entirely, and `consecutive whitespace IFS characters inside a string are treated as a single delimiter`. [Source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS)

Comment: @DigvijayS This is not related. In OP's example there is no word splitting inside `-ARGNAMEargvalue`. Actually, that is what OP is aksing: Why does `scriptname` correctly parse its argument despite the "missing" word splitting between `-ARGNAME` and `argvalue`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was wondering if this "additional feature" is implemented on script parsing side or a general feature for CLI arguments.

Comment: @KamilCuk if you paste your answer below I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @derlarsschneider I will upvote your answer if you paste it below.

Comment: @ChrisGraf : The standard option parsing mechanism for `bash` is [getopts](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/getopts.htm), but most programming languages have their own - some offer several - builtin mechanisms to do this job, and of course you are free to invent your own. Bear in mind that the more you deviate from the "standard" way of doing it, the more difficult it will be  for your users to rembember the rules.